# Can I use a MJX bugs 5w battery and/or charger for the MJX Bugs 5w 4k (upgraded version)?

Tags: quadcopters, lipo-batteries, batteries, charging

I am wondering if I can use the MJX bugs 5w battery for its upgraded version (MJX bugs 5w 4k) as it seems they both are the same dimensions, so it can slide into the drone. Also, I am wondering if I can use the bugs 5W charger to charge the bugs 5w 4k's battery. I am aware that by using a different charger to charge the bugs 5w 4k's battery, the charging times will differ, and that using the bugs 5w battery will decrease the normal flight time on the bugs 5w 4k.

Comment: You may be unlikely to get an answer on a relatively unknown drone, and might be better to contact the manufacturer or importer.

Answer (score 2):

As [@Robin Bennett](https://drones.stackexchange.com/users/124/) has suggested in a [comment](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/2166/#comment-2395), your best bet would be to contact the manufacturer to be certain.

However, the following are some things that need to be correct for the battery to be compatible and safe to use:

- Dimensions - check these exactly as there might be small changes (grooves, protrusions) to prevent an incompatible battery from fitting. Reusing moulds for plastic parts can save the manufacturer money!
- Weight - the battery needs to be light enough that the drone can lift it, but also that the drone remains sufficiently controllable to be safe while flying. Ensure the [CofG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_mass#Center_of_gravity) is within tolerance.
- Pinout - the batteries may appear to have the same connector in the same place, but the pins might have been changed or re-ordered electrically.
- Voltage - the voltage should be the same. In practice with LiPo batteries, it is more accurate to say they need the same number of cells so small differences (<0.5V) may not be a problem.
- Capacity - the charge capacity of a battery can be varied, but the C rating (the speed at which it can deliver its charge) must be high enough for the connected drone

As always, if you decide you want to test a drone modification yourself, ensure that you do so in a very safe location and controlled manner. Experimentation is a popular aspect of the hobby, but can result in broken equipment or injury. (And where insurance is required, ensure your modifications do not invalidate it.)